# How can I use my "gha" Docker cache to speed up Docker pull, as well as Docker build on Github Actions?

Tags: docker, caching, continuous-integration, github-actions, buildx

On Github Actions, I'd like to avoid having to pull my newly built Docker image from the registry when I have it in a cache (and this is the slowest part of my jobs)

My workflow is something like

1. Build an image (with all my dependencies baked in)
2. Run a command within the above image

As per the [Docker Build Push Action docs](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action/blob/master/docs/advanced/cache.md), setting up the `cache-to` and `cache-from` to point to `gha` has helped speed up step 1 a lot.

However, when I run `docker run ghcr.io/org/image:new-tag command`, it always starts with

```
Unable to find image 'ghcr.io/org/image:new-tag' locally
new-tag: Pulling from org/image
...
5402d6c1eb0a: Pulling fs layer
...
```

which takes around a 50 seconds (of around a total job time of ~75 seconds).

This seems unnecessary when there's a cache sat within reach that contains this information, however I don't know how to tell my `docker run` command how to make use of this cache as, as far as I can see, there's no `--cache-from=gha` equivalent option for docker run.

**How can I tell docker to look in the gha cache for an image when I call docker run on Github Actions?**

Answer (score 4):

We faced similar situation some time back but we recently found a github-actions which actually helps in caching the docker-layers & images b/w subsequent runs.

I am sure that your problem can also be solved with it. Here is the link to the gh-action **https://github.com/satackey/action-docker-layer-caching**.

**Configuration Example**
You can add the following lines above the docker run step to ensure caching to be done in gha

```
    - uses: satackey/action-docker-layer-caching@v0.0.11
      continue-on-error: true
```

Comment: This turned out to be slower than my current solution (pull from cache). Nice idea though.

Answer (score -1):

**However, you lose all the advantages of caching once you start building your images on a virtual machine that gets destroyed after every run.**

Please refer this tutorial will help you. https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/build-images-on-github-actions-with-docker-layer-caching